# limit and then group by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, cursors, offset-fetch

I have a mysql table having following structure :

```
payment_id(int auto_increment), 
emp_id(int), 
chargeTime(datetime), 
payment(double)
```

I need to have three latest (with respect to `chargeTime`) records of all `emp_id`. What should be the query?

Can anyone please help me? Without using cursor would be helpful.

Comment: Check this similar question at SO: [Selecting only 3 first joined items with uniq attribute within each group grouped by group by clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017689/selecting-only-3-first-joined-items-with-uniq-attribute-within-each-group-groupe/9057029#9057029)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL does not have the handy analytical functions that other SQL languages have. You can simulate them, tough, using some left outer join tricks:

```
   SELECT t1.payment_id
         ,t1.emp_id
         ,t1.cargeTime
         ,t1.payment
   FROM emps t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emps t2
     ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
    AND t1.chargeTime>=t2.chargetime
   GROUP BY t1.payment_id,t1.emp_id,t1.cargeTime,t1.payment
   HAVING count(1)<=3
```

This query should get you the last three (more recent) payments per emp_id. Should you need the first three, the AND t1.chargeTime>=t2.chargetime would be written as AND t1.chargeTime<=t2.chargetime.

You can test it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c1f9/1/0 Note that I have defined chargeTime as int for fastness sake, but should work with datetimes too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY chargeTime DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: This will get me three latest records with respect to chargetime. I would like to get three latest records wrt chargetime for all employees.